# Adding debug flags after configuration is done

Tags: cmake

We are currently porting a large project from GNU autotools to CMake. An open problem that is of great interest to our users (Scientific Computing: users are developpers) is to switch to debug compiler flags without reconfiguring the whole project.

There is of course a workaround to add some thing like

```
set_property(TARGET <target> PROPERTY COMPILE_FLAGS <debugflags>)
```

to the CMakeLists.txt and run

```
make target
```

and count on cmakes caching abilities to only configure that particular

But for our users that are used to automakes

```
make CXXFLAGS="<debugflags>" <target>
```

this is no convincing way to go.

The same goes for having 2 built directories, one with and one without debug flags.

I have looked for more possibilites to mimic such behaviour without success. Do you know any? Or do you know whether any such features are planned for future cmake releases?

Comment: What's the problem with reconfiguring? If everything is cached by CMake anyway it shouldn't make a big difference if you take into account that enabling debug requires recompilation/relinking of your code. And just to add, the CMake way to do this with single configuration build environments (like make) is using two binary directories.

Comment: The "problem" is that you have to modify your CmakeLists file and afterwards undo that change. As I see it, a CMakeLists file shouldnt be subject to daily changes. While this is not really a big deal, a solution would still help us to convince automake supporters.

Answer (score 1):

> The "problem" is that you have to modify your CmakeLists file and
>   afterwards undo that change

You don't need to change the CMakeLists file for this. CMake allows [specifying a build type](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE) on the command line for make based generators:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug [...] && make
```

This already adds the `-g` compile flag for you. If you need additional project specific flags, you can add them conditionally depending on the build type.

```
if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")
    # do your stuff
endif()
```

Note that once you have specified a build type, CMake will keep using that same build type for all subsequent runs unless you explicitly set a different one through the command line or delete the cache.

Comment: thx, i see how that is solving the isse of editing CmakeLists.txt. Unfortunately in some cases it is not only debugflags which need to be added to a single target, but also compile definitions (-D...) and other arbitrary stuff. I dont see how this can be acheived with this approach.

Comment: @DominicKempf Any reason you cannot just add an appropriate CMake option for those parameters? Also, consider educating your customers out of their irrational fear of having to re-run CMake every now and then. CMake is a different tool than autotools and it requires different patterns of use. In particular, a reconfigure run in CMake is usually a lot less painful then a reconfigure in autotools.